# Get an unexpected output when I try to use simple math operators in C

Tags: c, math, operators

I just wanted to test simple operators in different data types in C and there is an unexpected output

INPUT

```
    printf("%.2f \n", 10.0 + 4.0 + 5);
    printf("%d \n", 10 + 4);
    printf("%d \n", 12 * 5);
    printf("%.5f \n", 12 * 5);
```

OUTPUT

```
19.00 
14 
60 
19.00000
```

I don't understand why I got 19.00000 output when I tried to multiply 12 * 5

Comment: `12 * 5` is `int`. You can't print it with `%f`

Comment: But I am getting an output what is the reason for it? Shouldn't it give me a syntax error or another error?

Answer (score -1):

You are getting the result of because `printf("%.5f \n", 12 * 5);` multiplies an integer 12 with integer 5 but returns a float. So the output you get is a float.
However, to return float value, you can multiply with float value(s) or type cast them as float.

Some examples,

```
printf("%.5f \n", 12.0 * 5.0);
printf("%.5f \n", 12.0 * 5);
printf("%.5f \n", (float)12 * 5);
```

Comment: The code makes sense, the wording doesn't.

Comment: `12 * 5` has type `int` not `float`, and the `%f` operator expects `double`.  The problem an `int` is passed where at _runtime_ it is interpreted as a `double` - worse an `int` is typically a narrower type than a `double` so it is not even deterministic behaviour.  It is misleading to cast it to `float` since it will in any event be converted to `double` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).  Better example: `printf( "%.5f \n", (double)12 * 5);`